# AngularJS Directive - ng-click not working when using the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I'm facing a problem with my new directive. The variables are not being actualized when ng-click. I've found some answers here but all of them call a method. I'm just changing the value of 2 variables when there's a click.

Directive:

```
pmcApp.directive('sorting', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'AECM',
        templateUrl : 'partials/directives/sorting.html',
        replace : true,
        scope : {
            title : "@",
            field : "@"
        }
    }
});
```

TemplateURL:

```
<a href="" ng-click="sortType = '{{field}}'; sortReverse = !sortReverse;"> 
    {{title}}
    <span ng-show="sortType == '{{field}}' && !sortReverse"                        
      class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes font-size-10"></span> 
    <span ng-show="sortType == '{{field}}' && sortReverse"
      class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt font-size-10"></span>
</a>
```

html

```
<!-- Using directive - Not work when we click -->
<td><sorting title="First Name" field="firstName"></td>
<td><sorting title="Last Name" field="lastName"></td>
<!-- Not using directive - work when we click -->
<td>
    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'username'; sortReverse = !sortReverse;"> 
        Email 
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'username' && !sortReverse"                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes font-size-10"></span> 
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'username' && sortReverse"                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt font-size-10"></span>
    </a>
</td>
```

Code generated on browse is almost identical for all TDs as you can see bellow

```
<td>
    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'firstName'; sortReverse = !sortReverse;" title="First Name" field="firstName" class="ng-binding ng-isolate-scope"> 
        First Name 
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'firstName' &amp;&amp; !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes font-size-10 ng-hide"></span> 
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'firstName' &amp;&amp; sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt font-size-10 ng-hide"></span>
    </a>
</td>

<td>
    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'lastName'; sortReverse = !sortReverse;" title="Last Name" field="lastName" class="ng-binding ng-isolate-scope"  > 
        Last Name 
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'lastName' &amp;&amp; !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes font-size-10 ng-hide"></span> 
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'lastName' &amp;&amp; sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt font-size-10 ng-hide"></span>
   </a>
</td>

<td>
    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'username'; sortReverse = !sortReverse;"> 
        Email 
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'username' &amp;&amp; !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes font-size-10"></span> 
        <span ng-show="sortType == 'username' &amp;&amp; sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt font-size-10 ng-hide"></span>
    </a>
</td>
```

When we click on Email it works normal. But when we click on First Name or Last Name which were created with the directive it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `sorting` directive isn't change the property for the parent scope.  You are modifying the local scope of the `sorting` directive and not the parent scope like email is.